# Index was outside the bounds of the array (500th?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Calling the function on load and the error is pointing to that. I don't get the index out of range error on debug only on publish.

```
    {
        string strLogonUser = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
        var credential = strLogonUser.Split(@"\".ToCharArray())[1];




        cnn.Open();
        SqlTransaction tran = cnn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedure";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserLogin", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = credential;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }




    [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   _Default.ReadUser() +357
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +46
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Comment: Is LOGON_USER different when you're debugging? More specifically, does the other not contain a '\'?

Comment: Why don't you do a check to see it there is a "\" also I would recommend putting that code around a Try{}Catch{} \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you allow anonymous access so you will have a blank string in that variable

Comment: the test server wasnt properly setup.

Answer (score 5):

Well you'd definitely get that error if the `LOGON_USER` server variable doesn't contain a backslash... you'd be taking element 1 (the second element) of a single-element array.

It sounds like you should add more logging to record the value before you split.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a check for `"LOGON_USER"` variable:

```
string strLogonUser = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strLogonUser))  // <<<<<<
    throw new ArgumentException();  

var credential = strLogonUser.Split(@"\".ToCharArray())[1];
```

Seems like this variable is not set.